# How to grouping an sub array in one column php

Tags: php, laravel

I have array like this :

```
[
   0: {name: "Judi", age: 15, hobby: "playing a game"},
   1: {name: "Judi", age: 15, hobby: "swimming"},
   2: {name: "Judi", age: 15, hobby: "playing a basketball"},
   3: {name: "Jedi", age: 14, hobby: "coding"},
   4: {name: "Jedi", age: 14, hobby: "reading"},
   5: {name: "Jedi", age: 14, hobby: "listen to the music"},
]
```

and I wanna make my data look like this :

```
[
   0: {name: "Judi", age: 15, hobby: "playing a game, swimming, playing a basketball"},
   0: {name: "Jedi", age: 14, hobby: "coding, reading, listen to the music"},
]
```

How to group my data like that? Thank You

Comment: Just loop, build a new array with all hobbies associated to 1 user, then build your new array. We are not here to make your code. Just try

Comment: no, I dont want people make my code, I just ask how to make my array is grouping sir, thank you and sorry...

Comment: You should at least try to code it yourself, then show what you have and where it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'name' field is the identifier you can accomplish this with a few Collection methods:

```
collect($data)->groupBy('name')->map(function ($group) {
    return ['hobby' => $group->pluck('hobby')->join(', ')] + $group->first();
})->values();
```

This assumes your data is an array of arrays.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Creating Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#creating-collections) `collect`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) :

- [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby)
- [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map)
- [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)
- [`join`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join)
- [`first`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first)
- [`values`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values)

Comment: thanks sir for the feedback, I will read first your code, And why using collect sir for solving my problem?

Comment: @LuckALip to wrap the data in an object that has all these methods for utility

Comment: so for the recomended wrap the data in an object I must using collect sir for make it easier to manipulate my data?

Comment: you don't "have" to, this is just an option

Comment: okey sir got it, thanks for always give the detail answer sir I will make it your answer is best, I learn a lot from your answer sir

Answer (score 2):

It's really a pretty straightforward iteration and building up of a new array. Something like this.

```
<?php

$array = [
    ['name' => 'Judi', 'age' => 15, 'hobby' => 'playing a game'],
    ['name' => 'Judi', 'age' => 15, 'hobby' => 'swimming'],
    ['name' => 'Judi', 'age' => 15, 'hobby' => 'playing a basketball'],
    ['name' => 'Jedi', 'age' => 14, 'hobby' => 'coding'],
    ['name' => 'Jedi', 'age' => 14, 'hobby' => 'reading'],
    ['name' => 'Jedi', 'age' => 14, 'hobby' => 'listen to the music'],
];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $key = $item['name'] . $item['age'];
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
        $result[$key] = [
            'name'  => $item['name'],
            'age'   => $item['age'],
            'hobby' => '',
        ];
    }

    $result[$key]['hobby'] = $result[$key]['hobby'] ? $result[$key]['hobby'] . ', ' . $item['hobby'] : $item['hobby'];
}

var_dump(array_values($result));
```